# Create custom 'stage' for pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to get a list of failed stages (names) in a big pipeline. Multiple stages can fail due to parallel stages. This list of failed stages will be used to send an email in the `post` failure block.

I can do this with a script block like this, that is working alright:

```
script {
  try {
      // ...
  } catch (Exception e) {
      // store env.STAGE_NAME to be used in the post
      throw e
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I have to repeat this for all steps, which is too much repetition.
To solve this, I wanted to make a custom step to handle this in a generic way:

```
def mystage(String stageName, Closure body) {
    stage(stageName) {
        try {
            body()
        } catch (err) {
            env.FAILED_STAGES += (env.FAILED_STAGES) ? (stageName + "; ") : stageName
            throw err
        }
    }
}
```

This created env.FAILED_STAGES with a comma separated list of failed stage names.

Unfortunategly this does not work, eg. the following pipeline snippet gives an error:

```
mystage('Build') {
    steps {
        echo "Build"
    }
}
```

**Question: How can I create and use a custom mystage like this?**

Error:

```
WorkflowScript: 81: Expected a stage @ line X, column Y.
           mystage('Build') {
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can only call your user-defined function inside the `script` block.

The following works for me:

```
def class PipelineHelper {
    def steps

    PipelineHelper(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }

    void wrap(final Closure<?> action) {
        steps.echo "Trying action"
        try {
            action.call();
        } catch (final err) {
            steps.env.FAILED_STAGES = steps.env.FAILED_STAGES ? (steps.env.FAILED_STAGES + ";" + steps.env.STAGE_NAME) : steps.env.STAGE_NAME
            throw err
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('doing something') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def pipelineHelper = new PipelineHelper(this)
                    pipelineHelper.wrap {
                        sh "exit 255"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    post {
        always {
            sh "printenv | sort"
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
...
FAILED_STAGES=doing something
HOME=/home/jenkins/
HUDSON_COOKIE=e3b7...
HUDSON_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
...
```